# Why the C2662 error doesn't apply to a const reference to a std::unique_ptr<B> object?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, unique-ptr

I understand the reason for the error C2662 indicated below. My question is why the call
`a.GetB()->Get()` in `main()` doesn't incur in a similar error, as `GetB()` also returns a `const` reference to a `unique_ptr<B>` object  ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class B
{
    int i;

    public:
    B(int j) : i(j) {}
    int Get() { return i; }
};

class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> uptrB;

    public:
    A(int i) : uptrB(new B(i)) {}
    const std::unique_ptr<B>& GetB() { return uptrB; }
    const B* GetB1() { return uptrB.get(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a(3);
    cout << a.GetB()->Get() << endl;
    cout << a.GetB1()->Get() << endl;  // error C2662:'B::Get' cannot conver 'this' pointer from 'const B' to 'B&'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const std::unique_ptr<B>` is analogous to `B* const`, that is, an immutable pointer to a mutable `B`—not `const B*`, a mutable pointer to an immutable `B`. If you wanted to get the same error from the `unique_ptr` version, you would need to write `std::unique_ptr<const B>`. As it is, you are returning the `unique_ptr` by `const` reference, but the `B` to which it refers is not `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a const reference from your `getB()` method. You cannot change the address to which a const reference points. Yet calling `get()` on the returned object would give you the pointer. That is not a good thing to try!